# Freeform not working?

Tags: multi-site-manager, solspace-freeform

Would there be any reason why my 3 Freeform forms wouldn't do the following:

- Notify Admin
- Save submission at all
- fields in submission are empty

Below is my Freeform code:

```
{exp:freeform:form
    form_id="4"
    form:class="contact-form"
    form:id="contact-form"
    required="full_name|email"
    return="focusform3/results/%%entry_id%%"
    notify_admin="yes"
    admin_notify="ADMINS EMAIL ADDRESS" 
    admin_notification_template="focus_form_3"
    notify_user="yes"
    user_email_field="email"
    user_notification_template="focus_form_3"
}
```

Each of the 3 forms has 11 fields and are exactly the same just the form and admin email is different per form.  Each form has the same notification template layout.

I tested each form twice.  Each time with a different email address for admin.  made sure this email was also updated in the form, form notification and the form code in the template.  Each time it worked as it should.  Client however tested each form and either her submission didnt save, was incomplete with empty fields when she filled out all fields and at times didnt receive an admin email.

My EE install is the following:

- EE 2.5.5
- MSM 2.1.3
- Freeform 4.0.10

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What other factors are at play here? You you have AJAX/JS validation, .htaccess rewrites, captcha, etc? Would be great to see what the rest of the code in your template, or if you created a new, simplified template with barebones code and see if any difference is made. :)

You should also have a look at the Freeform Troubleshooting guide for more information about common conflicts and errors:
http://www.solspace.com/docs/freeform/troubleshooting/

Answer (score 0):

This won't be all the problems, but maybe the client needed to fill out a captcha and it wasn't included in the form so it didn't submit? Also, Solspace has their own forum and you might get better support thru that.

Comment: Snaptcha is the only captcha in the form